# dplyr clashes with testthat package when matches is used

Tags: r, dplyr, testthat

I am getting an error because `testthat::matches` clashes with `dplyr::matches`, and I want to know how to use `testthat::test_file` to check functions which contain calls to `matches()`, without having to specify `dplyr::matches` in the function body.

E.g.:

```
> testthat::test_file('tmp_fn_testthat_test.R')

Attaching package: ‘testthat’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    matches

The following object is masked from ‘package:purrr’:

    is_null

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in -matches("tmp") : invalid argument to unary operator In addition: Warning message:
package ‘testthat’ was built under R version 3.2.5 

DONE =========================================================================================================================================
```

This error can be reproduced by saving the following code in a file called `tmp_fn_testthat_test.R` in your working directory, and running the command `testthat::test_file('tmp_fn_testthat_test_20161115.R')`. Note that sourcing or running the `expect_equal` command while `testthat` is not loaded makes the test pass.

```
tmp_fn <- function() {
    tmp_df <- data.frame(tmp_a = 1, tmp_b = 2)

    tmp_df %>%
        select(-matches('tmp')) %>%
        ncol


}

testthat::expect_equal(tmp_fn(), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

[This is a known issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/2020) with dplyr 0.5. The recommended solution is to use an explicit namespace prefix: `dplyr::matches`.

Comment: I understand that, but my issue here is that I am explicitly trying not to have to load `testthat` by prefixing all the tests with `testthat::`, so that the tests work if I source the file. For whatever reason when you run `testthat::test_file` it insists on loading the package.

Answer (score 0):

A work around appears to be commenting out the `library(testthat)` in the definition of `testthat::test_file`, and making function calls explicit (not sure whether this will have bad side effects):

```
my_test_that_file <- function (path, reporter = "summary", env = testthat::test_env(), start_end_reporter = TRUE, 
          load_helpers = TRUE) 
{
    # library(testthat)
    reporter <- testthat:::find_reporter(reporter)
    if (load_helpers) {
        testthat:::source_test_helpers(dirname(path), env = env)
    }
    lister <- testthat:::ListReporter$new()
    if (!is.null(reporter)) {
        reporter <- testthat:::MultiReporter$new(reporters = list(reporter, 
                                                       lister))
    }
    else {
        reporter <- lister
    }
    testthat::with_reporter(reporter = reporter, start_end_reporter = start_end_reporter, 
                  {
                      lister$start_file(basename(path))
                      testthat::source_file(path, new.env(parent = env), chdir = TRUE)
                      testthat:::end_context()
                  })
    invisible(lister$get_results())
}
```